# How to retrieve list using child added event of firebase in flutter?

Tags: firebase, firebase-realtime-database, dart, flutter

I want to retrieve a list from my firebase realtime database using child added method of firebase using Stream object. I have configured my app like the following, but I get only 1 "question" (the newest one) being loaded, and the rest is not loaded at all.

I do have a lot more than 5 questions in my database. How can I get a list of 5 newest questions from my realtime database?

```
class _QuestionPageState extends State<QuestionsPage> {
  List _questions = [];    

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return new Scaffold(
      appBar: new AppBar(
        title: new Text(widget.title),
        body: new StreamBuilder(
        stream: FirebaseDatabase.instance
            .reference()
            .child('questions')
            .limitToLast(5)
            .onChildAdded,
        builder: (context, snap) {
          if (snap.hasError) return new Text('Error: ${snap.error}');
          if (snap.data == null)
            return new Center(
              child: new CircularProgressIndicator(),
            );
          print(snap.data.snapshot.key);
          print(snap.data.snapshot);
          final question = snap.data.snapshot.value;
          this._questions.add(question);
          return new ListView.builder(
            itemCount: this._questions.length,
            itemBuilder: (context, index) {
              print("question");
              print(this._questions[index]["meta"]["question"]);
              return new Text(this._questions[index]["meta"]["question"]);
            },
          );
        },
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

[Updated]
This is the database structure

[image: This is the structure of my database]

Comment: Could you please attach your database file to this question?

Comment: @AkshayNandwana I just added a image of my database

Comment: @farhana sure, go a head

Comment: @farhana I feel stupid lol Go ahead!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try not using "onChildAdded". That only gets the most recently added child. You want all the children, but want to limit yourself to the 5 most recent (which you are doing with limitToLast).

Comment: On iOS the childAdded event fires once for each existing child. Why doesn't it do the same for Flutter?? Here is the language from the docs on the FIRDataEventTypeChildAdded: "Retrieve lists of items or listen for additions to a list of items. This event is triggered once for each existing child and then again every time a new child is added to the specified path. The listener is passed a snapshot containing the new child's data." Source: https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/ios/lists-of-data

Comment: That' dumb - get _all_ the children?!! What if there are 100,000,000,000,000?

@EricDuffett's response worked for me, although I would like to be able to cancel the listener earlier, because Firebase limit the number of concurrent connections.  JavaScript would let you refer to the returned `updates` and cancel it when you'd counted 5 results, but Dart doesn't seem to like that.

Answer (score 3):

I ran into this problem as well and found it easier to NOT use a StreamBuilder Widget. When using a StreamBuilder I had to use .onValue instead of .onChildAdded in order to return all of the children, but the .onValue returned the children in an unpredictable order because it was coming back as a map.

Instead, I think it's best to create a StreamSubscription and call it in the initState() like below. New children get added to the array, and the array is used to build out the ListView. I am inserting new children at index 0 so that the newest posts are at the top of the table.

```
class NotificationsFeedPage extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _NotificationsFeedPageState createState() => _NotificationsFeedPageState();
}

class _NotificationsFeedPageState extends State<NotificationsFeedPage> {

  List <Notification> notificationList = [];

  StreamSubscription <Event> updates;

  @override
  void initState() {
    // TODO: implement initState
    super.initState();

    updates = FirebaseDatabase.instance.reference().child('notifications').child(currentUser.uid).limitToLast(50).onChildAdded.listen((data) {
      notificationList.insert(0, Notification.fromFireBase(data.snapshot));
      setState(() {

      });
    } );
  }

  @override
  void dispose() {
    // TODO: implement dispose

    updates.cancel();
    super.dispose();
  }
```

Where notification is a custom class as follows:

```
class Notification {
  String name;
  bool isComment;
  String user;
  String comment;

  Notification.fromFireBase(DataSnapshot snapshot) {
    this.name = snapshot.value["name"] ?? 'Unknown user';
    this.isComment = snapshot.value["isComment"] ?? false;
    this.user = snapshot.value["user"] ?? '';
    this.comment = snapshot.value["comment"] ?? '';
  }
}
```

This continues to listen until the view is disposed. Listening stops when updates.cancel() is called.